# mexGetData() outputs zeros

Tags: c, matlab, casting

I have the following `matlab mex` function:

```c
void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],int nrhs,   const mxArray *prhs[] ){

//Declare variables for the input arguments.

size_t lengthh;      /* input scalar */
double *inNoise;       /* 1xN input matrix */
float (*inGlucose)[12];       // 1xN input matrix float (*PatchSet)[64];
double *inDates;       /* 1xN input matrix */

if(nrhs != 4) {
    mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("MyToolbox:fullLoop:nrhs", "4 inputs required.");
}
/*if(nlhs != 1) {
    mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("MyToolbox:arrayProduct:nlhs",
                  "One output required.");
}*/
(void) nlhs; (void) plhs;

// make sure the first input argument is an array 
if( mxIsComplex(prhs[0]) || !mxIsDouble(prhs[0]) ) {
    mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("MyToolbox:fullLoop:notDouble","1:Input matrix must be type double.");
}
if( !mxIsDouble(prhs[1]) || mxIsComplex(prhs[1]) ) {
    mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("MyToolbox:fullLoop:notDouble","2:Input matrix must be type double.");
}

if( !mxIsDouble(prhs[2]) || mxIsComplex(prhs[2])|| mxGetNumberOfElements(prhs[2]) < 1 ) {
    mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("MyToolbox:arrayProduct:notDouble","3:Input matrix must be type long int.");
}

if( mxIsComplex(prhs[3]) || mxGetNumberOfElements(prhs[3])!=1 ) {
    mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("MyToolbox:arrayProduct:notDouble","4:Input scalar must be type double.");
}

// check that number of rows in second input argument is 1
if(mxGetM(prhs[0])!=1) {
    mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("MyToolbox:arrayProduct:notRowVector","5:1st argument must be a row vector.");
}
if(mxGetM(prhs[1])!=1) {
    mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("MyToolbox:arrayProduct:notRowVector","6:2nd argument must be a row vector.");
}
if(mxGetM(prhs[2])!=1) {
    mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("MyToolbox:arrayProduct:notRowVector","7:3rd argument must be a row vector.");
}

printf("Sizes: %d %d %d \n", mxGetNumberOfElements(prhs[0]), mxGetNumberOfElements(prhs[1]), mxGetNumberOfElements(prhs[2]));

/******************************************PROBLEM*****************************************************/
inNoise = (double *)mxGetData(prhs[0]);//mxGetData
inGlucose = (float (*)[12]) mxGetData(prhs[1]);//PatchSet = (float (*)[64]) mxGetData(prhs[0]);
lengthh = mxGetScalar(prhs[3]);
/******************************************************************************************************/


printf("length: %d\n",lengthh);
int i;
for (i=0;i<lengthh;i++){
    printf("%f -- %f\n",inGlucose[i],inNoise[i]);
}
//free(gStat);

return;
}
```

The problem is in the section separated by the line of asterisks.

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/223249-float-input-data-for-mex-not-compiling-the-code) to cast the arrays. 
Although the `double array` (inNoise) is properly read by the program, it returns an array of 0's for inGlucose.

There seems to be a fix to this in Matlab 2018A, but for unavoidable reasons I could only find 2016B.

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: why not just `inGlucose = (float (*)) mxGetData(prhs[1]);` ? Also, is the second input to your mex function of single class in MATLAB? Otherwise this wont work, there is not casting done by `mexGetData`

Comment: @AnderBiguri When I do that I get following warning:
 `warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]`

Comment: @AnderBiguri the 2nd input is an array of float

Comment: Yeah, I meant declaring it as `float * inGlucose` or are you triyint to use 2D matrices? Do you know that in MATLAB, all matrices are internally 1D? You mean an array of `single` in MATLAB right? (its the same thing but its called single in MATLAB )

Comment: @AnderBiguri yes, the input is an 1D array

Comment: So why are you even using the bracket notation? why not just the same notation as with the `inNoise` variable?

Comment: @AnderBiguri The problem is the `float` type. The array I'm passing as input is of type float (this one is assigned to inGlucose. `mxGetData` returns a double pointer. I also tried with `mxGetPr`, but the result is the same

Comment: All those times you you are telling me that the inputs are `single`, or float. They are not. You throw an error if they are not `double`  with `!mxIsDouble(prhs[1])`. The second input **IS NOT** a float

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`float (*inGlucose)[12]` is an array of pointers to 32-big floats. You are taking an array of double-precision float values and interpreting it as an array of pointers. It’s weird the program didn’t crash hard.

Instead, take the `double*` and copy the values over to a `float` array if you need them in that format.

```
double *inGlucoseD;
float inGlucose[12];
//...
inGlucoseD = mxGetPr(prhs[1]);
for (int ii=0; ii<12; ++ii) {
   inGlucose[ii] = inGlucoseD[ii];
}
```

Also test to make sure you have 12 input values to copy...

Note that `mxGetPr` is simpler here than `mxGetData` because you’ve already established it is a double array.

Comment: this is different behavior though, as `mxGetData` will give you the pointer to the MATLAB variable while this solution makes a copy

Comment: @Ander: If OP needs `float` values, they need to be copied. Note the `mxIsDouble` test for this input. The `mxArray` contains doubles.

Comment: No they don't. They need to be copied if the second input is enforced to be a double prior, but you can also input floats to the mex function (which is what OP told me they are doing, which is obviously not true though)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just

```
float * inGlucose= (float *)(mxGetData(prhs[1]));
```

This works only if your second input is a float (or `single` in MATLAB), so you also need to change your input error-checking code. However you insist in your comments that the second input is a float.

When you call this code, just make sure you do

`mymexfile(... , single(glucose), ..., ...)`